python-Playwright using xpath to locate child element causing error
Playwright will report an error when querying child elements using xpath syntax based on already located elements. I tried tds[1].query_selector('./span')
I know that Playwright can use xpath syntax to locate elements based on the current element. Why does my query not work?

tds[1].query_selector('xpath=./span')

This is the correct way of writing

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
